# Understanding ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Please can someone confirm my understanding of ES modules?

In `javascripts/bar.js`:

```
var foo = 2;

export function Bar() {}
```

In `index.html`

```
 <script>
   import { Bar } from 'javascripts/bar';
   var b = new Bar(); // Instantiates an instance of Bar.
 </script>
```

Under the hood the ES6 engine will load `bar.js` when it evaluates `import { Bar } from 'javascripts/bar';`, and block upon return of that module over HTTP? Or is `bar.js` downloaded prior to evaluation of the script in `index.html`?

Because `bar.js` is loaded using the `import` keyword, the globals in `bar.js` are scoped to that module and are not visible globally?

Now if I want to concatenate modules, I will continue to need to wrap my modules in IIFEs, so that their scopes remain distinct (or at least use a build step that does this under the hood)?

Comment: Great question. That looks right. I'd love to confirm, but I am not certain enough, especially about the last 2 sentences. +1'ing because it'd be great to get an answer that explains some edge cases.

Answer (score 5):

> Under the hood the ES6 engine will load bar.js when it evaluates import { Bar } from 'javascripts/bar';, and block upon return of that module over HTTP? Or is bar.js downloaded prior to evaluation of the script in index.html?

There is no correct answer to this yet, because there is no specification for how modules are loaded. ES2015 only specifies the module syntax, but how runtimes interpret that is not yet standardized. For example, it's very unlikely any loader specification that is eventually implemented will allow you to omit the `.js` as you do. And it's also very unlikely that `<script>` tags will be allowed to use `import`.

However, setting aside any syntactic missteps you made, I can tell you in general terms what is *likely* to be standardized for the browser loader. It is the latter: imports are determined and downloaded ahead of time, before any script execution happens. (For the Node.js loader, however, it is likely to be blocking.)

> Because bar.js is loaded using the import keyword, the globals in bar.js are scoped to that module and are not visible globally?

That depends on what you mean by globals. If you declare a global with e.g. `window.x = 5`, that will still mutate the global object. Modules do not get separate global objects to mess with.

However, if you mean "accidental" globals like those declared with `var` or `function` declarations at the top-level, the answer is that in modules top-level `var` and `function` declarations do not cause global properties to be defined.

(Note that in both modules and scripts, top-level `let` and `const` declarations do not create properties on the global object.)

> Now if I want to concatenate modules, I will continue to need to wrap my modules in IIFEs, so that their scopes remain distinct (or at least use a build step that does this under the hood)?

If you want to concatenate modules, you're going to have a lot bigger problems than those you describe. For example, `import` and `export` are only usable at the top level, and not inside an IIFE. Modules are not meant to be concatenated, as doing so is [actively harmful to performance](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/fwd-are-es6-modules-in-browsers-going-to-get-loaded-level-by-level#content-4) given modern browsers and servers.