# js call function via closure vs call on es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I have 2 functions defined like this:

```
export function builder(){ ... };
export function action() { return () => builder() };
```

Now I am trying to write a test that mock the builder function and return {};

```
 import * as m from 'redux/modules/mymodule';

 it('call buildSolrUrl', () => {
  const spy = expect.spyOn(m, "builder").andReturn({});
  m.action()();
  expect(spy.calls.length).toEqual(1);
 });
```

The problem is that builder does not get mock in that case.
If I change my code for:

```
export function action() { return () => this.builder() };
```

The method is mocked but my program does not work anymore because action() return a function that is executed later and `this` is not resolved to the right object.

To resume: My code works because the call to builder() is done via closure.
The tests are unable to mock the function that way because the function is called via the closure.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Please try this `export default function builder(){ ... };` then `spyOn(m, 'default')....` !

Comment: This is not working. doing this way you are not mocking the builder() function and the code of the method is executed (which I do not want)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding ES6 modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471474/understanding-es6-modules)